# AS3 "Advanced" string manipulation

Tags: string, actionscript-3, air

I'm making an air dictionary and I have a(nother) problem. The main app is ready to go and works perfectly but when I tested it I noticed that it could be better. A bit of context: the language (ancient egyptian) I'm translating from does not use punctuation so a phrase canlooklikethis. Add to that the sheer complexity of the glyph system (6000+ glyphs).
Right know my app works like this :

- user choose the glyphs composing his/r word.
- app transforms those glyphs to alphanumerical values (A1 - D36 - X1A, etc).
- the code compares the code (say : A5AD36) to a list of xml values.
- if the word is found (A5AD36 = priestess of Bast), the user gets the translation. if not, s/he gets all the possible words corresponding to the two glyphs (A5A & D36).

If the user knows the string is a word, no problem. But if s/he enters a few words, s/he'll have a few more choices than hoped (exemple : query = A1A5AD36 gets A1 - A5A - D36 - A5AD36). 
What I would like to do is this:

query = A1A5AD36 //word/phrase to be translated;

varArray = [A1, A5A, D36] //variables containing the value of the glyphs.

Corresponding possible words from the xml : A1, A5A, D36, A5AD36.

Possible phrases: A1 A5A D36 / A1 A5AD36 / A1A5A D36 / A1A5AD36.

Possible phrases with only legal words: A1 A5A D36 / A1 A5AD36.

I'm not I really clear but to things simple, I'd like to get all the possible phrases containing only legal words and filter out the other ones.
(example with english : TOBREAKFAST. Legal = to break fast / to breakfast. Illegal = tobreak fast.

I've managed to get all the possible words, but not the rest. Right now, when I run my app, I have an array containing A1 - A5A - D36 - A5AD36. But I'm stuck going forward.

Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you :)

```
function fnSearch(e: Event): void {
var val: int = sp.length; //sp is an array filled with variables containing the code for each used glyph.
for (var i: int = 0; i < val; i++) { //repeat for every glyph use.
    var X: String = ""; //variable created to compare with xml dictionary
    for (var i2: int = 0; i2 < val; i2++) { // if it's the first time, use the first glyph-code, else the one after last used.
        if (X == "") {
            X = sp[i];
        } else {
            X = X + sp[i2 + i];
        }
        xmlresult = myXML.mot.cd; //xmlresult = alphanumerical codes corresponding to words from XMLList already imported
        trad = myXML.mot.td; //same with traductions.
        for (var i3: int = 0; i3 < xmlresult.length(); i3++) { //check if element X is in dictionary
            var codeElement: XML = xmlresult[i3]; //variable to compare with X
            var tradElement: XML = trad[i3]; //variable corresponding to codeElement
            if (X == codeElement.toString()) { //if codeElement[i3] is legal, add it to array of legal words.
                checkArray.push(codeElement); //checkArray is an array filled with legal words.
            }
        }
    }
}
var iT2: int = 500 //iT2 set to unreachable value for next lines.
for (var iT: int = 0; iT < checkArray.length; iT++) { //check if the word searched by user is in the results.
    if (checkArray[iT] == query) {
        iT2 = iT
    }
}
if (iT2 != 500) { //if complete query is found, put it on top of the array so it appears on top of the results.
    var oldFirst: String = checkArray[0];
    checkArray[0] = checkArray[iT2];
    checkArray[iT2] = oldFirst;
}
results.visible = true; //make result list visible
loadingResults.visible = false; //loading screen
fnPossibleResults(null); //update result list.
```

}

I end up with an array of variables containing the glyph-codes (sp) and another with all the possible legal words (checkArray). What I don't know how to do is mix those two to make legal phrases that way :

[image]

If there was only three glyphs, I could probably find a way, but user can enter 60 glyphs max.

Comment: You should either place a splitting character in your XML, or use strict format for glyphs' alphanumeric translation. Say, why is there a `A5A` glyph, why couldn't it be `A79`? This way your translated words will be parsed in one way, "A1-A5-AD36", because the alternate word would be "A1A79D36".

Comment: Each hieroglyph has an official code that allows it to be unique and be treated by a computer. This code is composed of 1 letter + a number between 1 & 999 and another letter (if variants of hieroglyph). That i cannot change, it's the universal way to deal with hieroglyphs. :) I'm updating my question with my code.

Comment: Oh, you cannot change the glyph code? Bad, then plain split them with a dash while serializing into a string, should do, the dash position will properly designate what hieroglyphs were used to form this string.

Comment: And yes, generating all possible phrases out of a 60-glyph string is an exponentia task, and needs to be optimized (somehow). Probably you might get some optimizations by learning how do they do that in Japanese, they have a comparable glyph library and a lot of cross-senses in the dictionary.

Comment: I hate exponential things, that's where I got left behind in math ;) Thank you for your answer, I'll research it.

Comment: Two questions: 1) You say there is no punctuation "a phrase canlooklikethis". Then how can these 2 phrases `A1A5A D36` and  `A1A5AD36` be different? 2) Where can one download the entire list of legal words? AKA a dictionary.

Comment: 1. Same as english i guess. The letters contained in tobreakfast can be separated to make "to break fast" and "to breakfast". So tobreakfast can mean "eating in the morning" and "not resistent", context (and ponctuation for english) help translate. In-app, the user enters the 3 glyphs so the query is "A1A5AD36". Each of those glyphs happens to be a word by itself (A1 = I, me. A5A = hidden and D36 = individual), A1A5A and A1A5AD36 don't exist, and A5AD36 is a word. So A1A5AD36 can only mean either A1 A5A D36 or A1 A5AD36.

Comment: 2. There are a few dictionaries in pdf format on the internet, one can also buy traditionals physical dictionaries (they are quite expansive). Mine (in xml format) is different because it is ordered by hieroglyph (glyph code actually) so I had to create a whole new structure. I can not give you the full version (the original author of the dictionary gave me permission to use his work, but the rights remains his), but here is a small sample if it can help. [link](https://mega.nz/#!nYhARCKS!_6B8jL1FY-0q-0hfEwozjp9tV7JXUTuNj9dZoQ3xeLQ)